# How to extract phone number and split to column in Google sheet?

Tags: regex, vba, google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to extract phone numbers in this format (123) 456-7890 and put each number in a separate column with format 1234567890 with no space, dash or parenthesis.

I am able to achieve this in Excel using VBA code below from another StackOverflow question, but not able to get it working on Google sheet

```
Sub ewqre()
    Dim str As String, n As Long, rw As Long
    Dim rgx As Object, cmat As Object, ws As Worksheet

    Set rgx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet4")

    With rgx
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        'phone number pattern is: ###-###-####
        .Pattern = "/^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})$/"
        For rw = 2 To ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            str = ws.Cells(rw, "A").Value2
            If .Test(str) Then
                Set cmat = .Execute(str)
                'populate the worksheet with the matches
                For n = 0 To cmat.Count - 1
                    ws.Cells(rw, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1) = cmat.Item(n)
                Next n
            End If
        Next rw
    End With

    Set rgx = Nothing: Set ws = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1B7_1JDaoeSd9hbS_eizNOK00qoui1KnkG7tBZbbpYo4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: The `.Pattern = "/^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})$/"` won't work in Excel VBA because the regex delimiters (together with anchors) will prevent strings from matching.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew you are correct. It's actually .Pattern = "[0-9,\-]{12}"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT(SPLIT(
 REGEXREPLACE(A2:A, "\(|\)|\-| ", ""), CHAR(10))), "\d+")))
```

[image]

---

or:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT(A2, CHAR(10)), 
 "\((.*)\(.T"),"\)|\s|\-", ""))
```

[image: 0]

true array formula would be:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT(A2:A, CHAR(10)), 
 "\((.*)\(.T"),"\)|\s|\-", "")))
```

Comment: Wow. That was fast. I have been at this all day. Thank you very much. I am extremely grateful

Comment: Feel like I commented a similar answer not too long ago. Love seeing how Sheets can do regex formulaically, much better than Excel.

Comment: @NKI I added ArrayFormula variation

Comment: @player0 I just noticed that if the numbers are not exactly in this (123) 456-7890, it returns an empty cell. An example is cell D3 on the link. Is there anyway to also catch 123) 456-7860?

Comment: sure: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT(A2:A, CHAR(10)), 
 "(.*)\(.T"),"\(|\)|\s|\-", "")))`

Comment: @player0 Thanks for update. One last thing. If the cell only contains (123) 456-7890 and nothing else. It returns an empty cell.

Comment: @player0 Also, can you explain briefing what is going in the formula? I want to understand how it works.

Comment: I made better one: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT(SPLIT(
 REGEXREPLACE(A2:A, "\(|\)|\-| ", ""), CHAR(10))), "\d+")))`

Comment: and it means: delete `(`,  `)`,  `-`, `-empty space-` from A2:A then split by char(10) eg every new line, then regexextract the number from each string and omit all errors with iferror

Comment: @Pie I wish I could, but don't have the knowledge to solve it. sry